# ioremap fails on physical address

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm

I have a ARM target.

I need to read out a physical address.
This address is a location in the parralel NOR flash rom.
The rom is directly on the address bus.

if i create a module with :

```
   if ((rmap = ioremap(ROM_BASE, ROM_SIZE)) == NULL)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "Mapping ROM failed\n");
    return -1;
}
```

(using base 0x40000000 size 0x100)
If fails : 
[ 1091.270686] Mapping ROM failed
insmod: error inserting 'rom.ko': -1 Operation not permitted

The target does not have /dev/mem in this case...
but with different kernel it has..and reading same address work.
So the address is correct and readable.

Thanks

Comment: try a larger size like 0x10000000, doesnt matter if you only access 0x100 of it.

Comment: #dwelch, Thank..but did try different sizes, all same result.

Comment: often a larger size helps, oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ioremap on arm ends up calling [__arm_ioremap_pfn_caller](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/ioremap.c#L258) with mtype = MT_DEVICE, which can fail in a number of ways:

- The address must not be defined as a RAM address (check meminfo)
- The process may be out of VM space (unlikely)
- There may be no free page table entries (architecture dependent)

For more on ARM memory allocation check [this page](http://elinux.org/Tims_Notes_on_ARM_memory_allocation)

Comment: Thanks for the info.
If i'm correct linux 2.6 (as this is) does not check RAM address.
But checking this i found a function __arm_ioremap..tried it and it works!!
I'm sure this isn't the neatest way..but good enough for my need at the moment.
So since this answer made me find a solution, i'm marking it as accepted.Thanks!